# Check if a file has headers and skip them on csv import

Tags: php, csv

Because of the nature of CSV files and more or less lack of standarization of that filetype, I am wondering if it is even possible to check if such files have headers or not. So far I created an basic importer for CSV files and now I am trying to implement as much validation as possible.

I found many threads in the internet about how to skip the first line, the few first lines, the last line, etc., but none of these which I have read mentions how to detect headers in a CSV file.

Here is part of my `csvImport()` method, which handles the CSV formatting, etc.:

```
public function csvImport($file) {
    $data = array();
    $delimiter = array(";", ",", "\t", "|");
    $mimes = array(
        'text/csv', 
        'application/csv', 
        'text/comma-separated-values', 
        'application/excel', 
        'application/vnd.ms-excel', 
        'application/vnd.msexcel', 
        'application/octet-stream', 
        'application/csv', 
        'application/x-csv', 
        'text/x-comma-separated-values', 
        'text/tab-separated-value text/x-csv'
    );

    if (is_file($file) && is_readable($file) && in_array($_FILES['file']['type'], $mimes)) {
        $handle = fopen($file, 'r');
        //...
```

How to determine, if a CSV file has headers or not?

Comment: There is no (syntactical) difference in CSV between a “header line”, and any actual “data” line. At most you can try and make an educated guess, based on the specific row contents. With a header line, you might be more likely to find descriptive _text_ in all columns, other data “types” such as numbers, dates, prices etc. should tend to occur rather infrequent in a header.

Comment: If this is for a UI where an actual human uploads CSV files, then you could let them decide upfront how many lines to skip, and if they don’t know beforehand, you could also show them the first couple of lines in a second step, and let them mark which one(s) are header lines, or something like that.

Comment: I sort of figured out workaround for some types of csv files, to be more specific if csv supposed to contain numbers only then all lines having non-numeric values could be skipped. But i can imagine such cases are rare.